# c# - Drag and Drop from one Treeview to another - WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have the DragAndDrop Event such as below for both my treeviews (treeV and treeV_IgnoreD):

```
 private void treeV_IgnoredDragDropEvent(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve the client coordinates of the drop location.
        Point targetPoint = treeV_Ignored.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

        // Retrieve the node at the drop location.
        TreeNode targetNode = treeV.GetNodeAt(targetPoint);

        // Retrieve the node that was dragged.
        TreeNode draggedNode = (TreeNode)e.Data.GetData(typeof(TreeNode));

        // Confirm that the node at the drop location is not 
        // the dragged node and that target node isn't null
        // (for example if you drag outside the control)
        if (!draggedNode.Equals(targetNode) && targetNode != null)
        {
            // Remove the node from its current 
            // location and add it to the node at the drop location.
            draggedNode.Remove();
            targetNode.Nodes.Add(draggedNode);

            // Expand the node at the location 
            // to show the dropped node.
            targetNode.Expand();

        }
    }

    private void treeV_Ignored_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move);
        MessageBox.Show("ola");
    }

    private void treeV_Ignored_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
```

These treeviews are populated from a Oracle dataset, and represent the same data.

I want to be able to drag an item from "treeV", and drop it within "treeV_Ignored".

How can I achieve that behaviour?

Comment: what you have done yet?

Comment: Did you use the recommended ItemDrag event?? And what happens?

Comment: @user6002727 I had an issue in my code above. I've so the drop location is on "treeV" (trying to do from "treeV_Ignored" - where the event above is, to "treeV). Even so, it doesn't work, why I move the mouse over the other treeview it's not allowed to drop, so I'm obviously missing something important.

Comment: @TaW I'm not sure I understand your question. I have all those events implemented. That one has: DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move);

Comment: You didn't show them at first. - Well, what happens when you try it? Also: Do not use MessageBox when testing mouse events! use Console.WriteLine, so you don't mess up focus etc..

Comment: Looks just like a simple mistake.  You want the ItemDrag event of the TreeV control, not TreeV_Ignored.

Answer (score 2):

your requirement is full fill with this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/DraganddropTreeNode.htm)
kindly look into.
Further more , you have to understand first, here `SplitContainer` is used for drag and drop purpose thorough which we can add our treeview to this control, so we easily drag any node to another tree. If you have any issue let me know